# Is accessing BufferedImage thread safe

Tags: java, graphics, bufferedimage

In Java, I have 2 threads that are both accessing (not modifying) the same BufferedImage. I'm simply drawing the buffered image into a separate Graphics2D objects with code like this.

```
Graphics2D g = getGraphics();
g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, null);
```

Is there any reason I need to synchronize access to the images?

*I know about the AWTEventThread not being thread safe etc. I'm just building some BufferedImages in a background thread.*

Thanks much...

Comment: To clarify, the buffered image is created before either of the threads are accessing the buffered image. They are both just accessing a non changing buffered image. The reason I ask is because BufferedImage isn't a mutable object. Its possible that g.drawImage could modify it. I assume it doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(The title of your question doesn't actually match the scenario described in the body, so I'm assuming that you are asking about both cases ...)

The two threads that are just accessing an (at that point) non-changing `BufferedImage` would not need to synchronize between themselves.

However, there does need to be a happens-before relationship between the thread that created and initialized the `BufferedImage` object in the first place and any threads that  subsequently read it.  Without that synchronization point, the reading threads *might* see stale values for parts of the image data structure.

Comment: From the way the question is posed this doesn't seem to be a problem (eg he creates the image before starting the threads) - in this case if the variable is assigned in the constructor one wouldn't even have to make myImage volatile.

Comment: @Voo - As far as I can see, there is not sufficient information to say when the threads were started, and whether this is sufficient to  give a happen-before relation.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading too much into it - but if he had not created the image he'd before starting the threads he'd at least need a if (img != null) and the usual scenarios where you'd do something like this would also ensure it. But sure I assume it could be possible.

Comment: @Voo - there is a happens-before relationship when a thread is started.  In the scenario you propose, it is sufficient to synchronize access to the shared image.

Answer (score 1):

Even in another, read-only thread, changes made on the EDT must become *visible*, and that requires *some* form of synchronization to create a [*happens-before*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) relation. Several alternatives are shown [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/threadwatch).